# How to get the full attendees list of Google Calendar Events

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm developing an application which works with the Google Calendar API. When I request that event in the context of individual attendee calendars, then the attendee list will differ across each attendee. A few of the attendees are never seen in the lists of the other participants. Not even the organizers attendees list contains all attendees. I really need to find a user context (organizer I assumed) from which I can retrieve a full list of all attendees.
I'm using a service account in Google to access the desired data.

I tried to vary the request parameters of the Google Calendar events list request (e.g. maxAttendees) and changed the scopes of the service account.

Does anybody know how I can make a request which gives me the full list of all participants of an event?

Best regards

Edit:

A generic example of the problem might be:

An event has the attendees A1 (organizer), A2, A3, A4, and 6 more: G6. Requesting the event

- with A1 calendarId leads to an attendee list A1 + G6
- with Ax calendarId to an attendee list of Ax + A1 + G6 where x is 2, 3, 4
- with a calendarId of one of G6 leads to an attendee list A1 + G6

Comment: What are the results that you are getting? Are you using the [events.get method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get)?

Comment: I use events.get and events.list - both lead to the same result.

Comment: Could you share your code to see if it can be reproduced?

Comment: In the very most cases my code - which is basically the code which is suggested on the Google developers sites - leads to the expected results, i.e. consistent results for all users of a shared event. Only very few events and requests show the described behavior. Hence it should be impossible for you to reproduce it with my code.